# Why does this bootstrap datepicker not show the datepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I have existing asp.net pages using bootstrap datepickers.

I need it now in a simple html page, so I copied the related link and script lines from the asp.net project into a bare minimum html file.

The datepicker never shows, and I have no idea what is wrong with it. I have looked aroud and searched the web for examples, but did not find out why it does not work.

Here's a little test file:

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>datepicker test</title>
    <link href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-2.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.12.0/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.6/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#datepicker").datetimepicker({
                format: "dd-MMM-yyyy"
            });
        })
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <form>
        <div class="input-append date" id="datepicker">
            <input size="16" type="text" value="" readonly>
            <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-th"></i></span>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Please advise,

TIA,

Guido

Comment: mind to publish this in jsfiddle? missing glyphicon? are you sure the versions of jquery and jquery-ui are fine (in combination)? any errors visible in the browser's debugger ("F12 console")?

Comment: AFAIK, `datetimepicker` should be initialized on `input` field. Try initializing it on `input` field and don't make it `readonly` for proper check..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You misspelled the function to call the datepicker. It's

```
 $("#datepicker").datepicker({
     format: "dd-MMM-yyyy"
 });
```

And you typed 'dateTIMEpicker'